# how to send approve variable in Sharepoint Designer WF

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, approval-process

I have a requirement where i send an email using SharePoint Designer to a person and when he clicks on the link on the email in outlook it has to approve the task without opening SharePoint site.

To configure it i am thinking of send a approve variable in the link. but how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is if you sync the task with outlook then you can click the `Approve this task` button in outlook.Something like this:

[image]

Read more here: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/265384.aspx

Comment: I am not trying to use out-of-box workflow. I am using SharePoint Designer workflow. Is there any option for SharePoint Designer List Workflow like this ?